# why is my console.log not showing anything in chrome?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=caca2ca6';

const App = () => {
                        
  const searchMovies = async (title) => {
                     
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
          
    const data = await response.json();

    
    console.log(data.Search);
  }

  
  useEffect=(() => {
    searchMovies('Batman');
  }, []); 
      

    return(
      <h1>Apppi</h1>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```

the code above should show the movies title in the api on console, the tutorial im watching has title showed up. Can someone solve this for me? Thanks

Comment: Typo. You've got a rogue `=` between the function name (`useEffect`) and the `(...)` that should be next to it.

Comment: oh wooooowwwwww, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

there is syntax error in useEffct

remove = between useEffect and parentheses

```
useEffect(() => {
    searchMovies('Batman');
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Answer (score 0):

please always call the API in `try-catch`, this way your app will not crash and you may log error and you have to remove the `=` in useEffect before paranthesis.

```
const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=caca2ca6';
    
const App = () => {
                      
const searchMovies = async (title) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
        
      const data = await response.json();
  
      
      console.log(data.Search);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error)
    }
}


useEffect(() => {
  searchMovies('Batman');
}, []); 
    

  return(
    <h1>Apppi</h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```